# Groupings on SQL Timestamp Difference Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I inquired about this earlier, but wanted to post a new question with further details after receiving some feedback. I'm currently using the following query to find the time between records using my Date field (Datetime format).

```
SELECT Call_Created_By, Date,
       timestampdiff(minute, lag(Date, 1) OVER (ORDER BY Date), date) as 'Time Between Calls (min)'
FROM visits_master
ORDER BY Date;
```

This yields the following results-

```
  +-----------------+---------------------+--------------------------+
    | Call_Created_By | Date                | Time Between Calls (min) |
    +-----------------+---------------------+--------------------------+
    | User 1          | 2020-01-02 13:30:03 | 0                        |
    +-----------------+---------------------+--------------------------+
    | User 2          | 2020-01-02 13:33:41 | 3                        |
    +-----------------+---------------------+--------------------------+
    | User 1          | 2020-01-02 13:38:43 | 5                        |
    +-----------------+---------------------+--------------------------+
    | User 3          | 2020-01-02 13:38:49 | 0                        |
    +-----------------+---------------------+--------------------------+
```

While the query is functioning to find the difference between timestamps, I also want to sort it by the Call_Created_By field to ultimately look at the time between timestamps per user. My desired results are as follows-

```
+-----------------+---------------------+--------------------------+
| Call_Created_By | Date                | Time Between Calls (min) |
+-----------------+---------------------+--------------------------+
| User 1          | 2020-01-02 13:30:03 | 0                        |
+-----------------+---------------------+--------------------------+
| User 1          | 2020-01-02 13:38:43 | 8                        |
+-----------------+---------------------+--------------------------+
| User 2          | 2020-01-02 13:33:41 | 0                        |
+-----------------+---------------------+--------------------------+
| User 3          | 2020-01-02 13:38:49 | 0                        |
+-----------------+---------------------+--------------------------+
```

Thanks for your help.

Update- when trying this following query as suggested below

```
SELECT Call_Created_By, Date,
       timestampdiff(minute, lag(Date, 1) OVER (partition by Call_Created_By ORDER BY Date), date) as 'Time Between Calls (min)'
  FROM visits_master
ORDER BY Call_Created_By,Date;
```

I get the following results. You will see the time difference calculation does not function.

```
+-----------------+---------------------+--------------------------+
| Call_Created_By | Date                | Time Between Calls (min) |
+-----------------+---------------------+--------------------------+
| User 1          | 2020-01-02 15:01:15 | 0                        |
+-----------------+---------------------+--------------------------+
| User 1          | 2020-01-02 15:27:30 | 0                        |
+-----------------+---------------------+--------------------------+
| User 1          | 2020-01-02 15:27:30 | 0                        |
+-----------------+---------------------+--------------------------+
| User 1          | 2020-01-02 15:27:30 | 0                        |
+-----------------+---------------------+--------------------------+
| User 1          | 2020-01-02 15:27:30 | 26                       |
+-----------------+---------------------+--------------------------+
| User 1          | 2020-01-02 15:27:30 | 0                        |
+-----------------+---------------------+--------------------------+
| User 1          | 2020-01-02 15:42:57 | 15                       |
+-----------------+---------------------+--------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated query if you want to see by day the diff in timestamp records

```
select x.Call_Created_By
       ,x.date1
       ,max(time_between_calls) over(partition by call_created_by,grp) as time_between_calls_2
   from(
SELECT Call_Created_By
      ,Date1
      ,timestampdiff(minute, lag(Date1, 1) OVER (partition by Call_Created_By,cast(date1 as date) ORDER BY Date1), date1) as time_between_calls
      ,count(*) over(order by date1) as grp
  FROM t
)x
ORDER BY x.Call_Created_By
        ,x.Date1
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1b60695dcdc734d15a8b395125f47633

Query to consider cases where the timestamp of call is same as that of the previous record.

```
select x.Call_Created_By
       ,x.date1
       ,max(time_between_calls) over(partition by call_created_by,grp) as time_between_calls_2
   from(SELECT Call_Created_By
              ,Date1
              ,timestampdiff(minute, lag(Date1, 1) OVER (partition by Call_Created_By ORDER BY Date1), date1) as time_between_calls
              ,count(*) over(order by date1) as grp
         FROM t
        )x
ORDER BY x.Call_Created_By
        ,x.Date1
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=04788f49c032ae1ae0eca218a1b3bd9a

The change you would need is to partition by "Call_Created_By" field

```
SELECT Call_Created_By, Date,
       timestampdiff(minute, lag(Date, 1) OVER (partition by Call_Created_By ORDER BY Date), date) as 'Time Between Calls (min)'
  FROM visits_master
ORDER BY Call_Created_By,Date;
```

Comment: Thank you- when I run this, it does partition correctly by Call_Created_By, but the 'Time Between Calls (min)' calculation is then no longer accurate. For example a timestamp of 2020-01-02 15:27:30 following a timestamp of 2020-01-02 15:01:15 is showing a 'Time Between Calls (min)' calculation of 0.

Comment: can you share the list of values you have for the call_created_by which has this problem, by editing your question

Comment: Hi George- i updated the question with the results using your suggested query. Thank you.

Comment: the value where you see 26 is the first record with timestamp 15:27 which compared with the previous value of 15:01. After that you have got repeating values of 15:27, which is the reason why the values of the time_between_calls is set to 0

Comment: In case you wish to ignore records with same timestamp as previous value, then have a look at my updated answer and dbfiddle link

Comment: Aha I see now, this is perfect. Thank you for the help. One final question maybe you would know is can I reset this for each day? For example, the difference between the timestamp of 2020-01-03 15:24:17 and 2020-01-02 22:49:27 is 994. When it is moving on to the next day like this, I'd prefer it show 0 or null for that first record of the day. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: For doing that you would partition by the date field truncated without the timestamp portion. See the example https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1b60695dcdc734d15a8b395125f47633

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the `partition by`, if you want zero values, use the three-argument form of lag:

```
SELECT Call_Created_By, Date,
       timestampdiff(minute,
                     lag(Date, 1, date) OVER (PARTITION BY call_created_by ORDER BY Date),
                     date
                   ) as minutes_between_calls
FROM visits_master
ORDER BY Date;
```